# Which of the following function invocations is valid?

Tags: c, function, declaration

Consider the declarations

```
char first (int (*) (char, float)) ;

int second(char, float);
```

Which of the following function invocations is valid?

A)   `first (*second);`

B)   `first (&second);`

C)   `first (second);`

D)   none of the above

Can any one please explain me this code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: What is the other homework question? Then we can all go to the pub

Comment: why not ask your compiler

Comment: Option E — all of A, B and C are valid.

Comment: however i must say that until i tried it out i did not know the answer was E. I was very surprised to see C playing fast and loose with this. So I upvoted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three calls are valid.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
>   Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
>   operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
>   is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
>   returning type’’

Moreover you can even write

```
first( ******second );
```

That is a function designator used in expressions is implicitly converted to pointer to the function itself except of in fact one case when it is used as an operand of the & operator where the address of the function is taking explicitly.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void g( void ( *f )( void ))
{
    f();
}


void f( void )
{
    puts( "Hello!" );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    g( **********f );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello!
```

Take into account that the function `first` also could be declared like

```
char first (int (char, float)) ;
```

A function parameter having a function type is implicitly adjusted to pointer to function.

Comment: so `f` means `&f`, `*f` means `&f` and of course `&f` means `&f`

Comment: @pm100 Yes, you are right.

Comment: Vlad, is that (the standard) a polite way of saying "pointer-fiddling with functions will be ignored"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I am sorry I have not understood what you mean.